# Not equal strings by Encoding.Default.GetString in Core 2.1 and .net5 from equals byte arrays

Tags: c#, encoding, .net-5, asp.net-core-2.1

I got this trouble when rewrite my service to .net5. I check password hash, and it not equal with hash in DB. For example, I wrote small console programm. Results of work in Core 2.1 and .net5 are different

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   var password = "MlsU37z*!";
   var bytesOfHash = GetBytesOfHash(password);

   Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(bytesOfHash));
   var hashString = Encoding.Default.GetString(bytesOfHash);
   Console.WriteLine(string.Join("-", hashString.Select(ch => $"{(ushort)ch:X4}")));
   Console.WriteLine($"Hash string length = {hashString.Length}");
           
   Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Result for Core2.1:**

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
55-75-89-08-01-6D-B8-00-49-1D-44-C4-8E-9B-21-E2-5B-4F-59-41-00-43-4F-C5-B3-C3-53-E5-2F-95-06-24-30-A3-B6-87-0F-DB-31-C4-AE-D7-8C-AE-D9-BD-C8-9F-F1-04-E5-5F-A9-D7-9B-3B-21-51-FC-B4-44-23-D3-75-34-3B-1F-93-99-6C-D5-EE-D4-65-96-B4-16-2D-30-4E-B0-DD-D3-31-CF-53-0E

0029-FFFD-002A-0545-FFFD-FFFD-005F-003E-FFFD-FFFD-0023-007E-0009-FFFD-0048-007E-000E-FFFD-0070-FFFD-FFFD-0008-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-0075-0030-01CE-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-0071-FFFD-007D-FFFD-0024-0080-FFFD-0041-0058-FFFD-FFFD-007E-000D-0078-FFFD-0030-FFFD-FFFD-002D-FFFD-0664-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-0044-0062-0006-0002-0046-003F-FFFD-000E-000F-00C6-FFFD-0018-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-0059-FFFD-FFFD-0014-FFFD-FFFD-0066-000D-0044-FFFD-001B-0016-005D-005F-FFFD-0075-FFFD-0058-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-0014-FFFD-0017-006D-FFFD-03F4-FFFD-000B-FFFD-06D6-0039-0049-0048-000C-007B-FFFD-FFFD-006F-0062-FFFD-0063-FFFD-0077-FFFD-0041-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-005A-004B-FFFD-0005-FFFD-0002-FFFD-0040-015B-FFFD-0033-006A-006D-0021-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-0056-FFFD-0068-0056-FFFD-001A-FFFD-0057-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-0047-FFFD-FFFD-0035-0073-FFFD-003B-0040-3553-000C-FFFD-0010-0064-0028-FFFD-0039-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-0015-007D-001D-FFFD-0043-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-0023-FFFD-001F-0060-FFFD-0021-FFFD-0040-FFFD-004F-FFFD-FFFD-0005-FFFD-0052-FFFD-005B-000F-FFFD-000E-FFFD-FFFD-0029-0005-FFFD-002A-0010-0044-FFFD-058A-005A-0071-0036-FFFD-004C-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-0039-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-003A-FFFD-001D-FFFD-FFFD-0017-0078-FFFD-FFFD-005E-FFFD-0025-0007-0055-FFFD-0021-FFFD-FFFD-012D-FFFD-0076-0038-005E-006F-FFFD-FFFD-000F-0004-FFFD-FFFD-0020-FFFD-FFFD-0085-
FFFD-000E-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-005F-FFFD-FFFD-0016-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-0048-0077-000E-001D-FFFD-0005-0002-000A-FFFD-004F-FFFD-0027-000A-FFFD-003C-0020-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-0021-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-0051-FFFD-0014-FFFD-FFFD-0061-FFFD-0036-001B-0047-FFFD-0057-0017-FFFD-0061-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-002F-002E-002E-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-003C-0006-0392-007E-0049-FFFD-FFFD-004D-0038-FFFD-FFFD-0061-004D-0033-002E-0051-0053-FFFD-0033-FFFD-0033-0031-0057-FFFD-1A78-0013-FFFD-FFFD-005A-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-000E-0061-0026-FFFD-004C-FFFD-0048-0046-FFFD-0005-FFFD-0079-0047-FFFD-004B-FFFD-FFFD-0021-0031-0056-0034-FFFD-FFFD-0052-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-0071-FFFD-003D-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-0023-FFFD-006E-0023-FFFD-0078-FFFD-0004-FFFD-001B-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-0055-0075-FFFD-0008-0001-006D-FFFD-0000-0049-001D-0044-010E-FFFD-0021-FFFD-005B-004F-0059-0041-0000-0043-004F-0173-FFFD-0053-FFFD-002F-FFFD-0006-0024-0030-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-000F-FFFD-0031-012E-05CC-FFFD-067D-021F-FFFD-0004-FFFD-005F-FFFD-05DB-003B-0021-0051-FFFD-FFFD-0044-0023-FFFD-0075-0034-003B-001F-FFFD-FFFD-006C-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-0065-FFFD-FFFD-0016-002D-0030-004E-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-0031-FFFD-0053-000E

Hash string length = 478

**Result for .net5:**

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
55-75-89-08-01-6D-B8-00-49-1D-44-C4-8E-9B-21-E2-5B-4F-59-41-00-43-4F-C5-B3-C3-53-E5-2F-95-06-24-30-A3-B6-87-0F-DB-31-C4-AE-D7-8C-AE-D9-BD-C8-9F-F1-04-E5-5F-A9-D7-9B-3B-21-51-FC-B4-44-23-D3-75-34-3B-1F-93-99-6C-D5-EE-D4-65-96-B4-16-2D-30-4E-B0-DD-D3-31-CF-53-0E

0029-FFFD-002A-0545-FFFD-FFFD-005F-003E-FFFD-FFFD-0023-007E-0009-FFFD-0048-007E-000E-FFFD-0070-FFFD-FFFD-0008-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-0075-0030-01CE-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-0071-FFFD-007D-FFFD-0024-0080-FFFD-0041-0058-FFFD-FFFD-007E-000D-0078-FFFD-0030-FFFD-FFFD-002D-FFFD-0664-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-0044-0062-0006-0002-0046-003F-FFFD-000E-000F-00C6-FFFD-0018-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-0059-FFFD-FFFD-0014-FFFD-FFFD-0066-000D-0044-FFFD-001B-0016-005D-005F-FFFD-0075-FFFD-0058-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-0014-FFFD-0017-006D-FFFD-03F4-FFFD-000B-FFFD-06D6-0039-0049-0048-000C-007B-FFFD-FFFD-006F-0062-FFFD-0063-FFFD-0077-FFFD-0041-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-005A-004B-FFFD-0005-FFFD-0002-FFFD-FFFD-0040-015B-FFFD-0033-006A-006D-0021-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-0056-FFFD-0068-0056-FFFD-001A-FFFD-0057-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-0047-FFFD-FFFD-0035-0073-FFFD-003B-0040-3553-000C-FFFD-0010-0064-0028-FFFD-0039-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-0015-007D-001D-FFFD-0043-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-0023-FFFD-001F-0060-FFFD-0021-FFFD-0040-FFFD-004F-FFFD-FFFD-0005-FFFD-0052-FFFD-005B-000F-FFFD-000E-FFFD-FFFD-0029-0005-FFFD-002A-0010-0044-FFFD-058A-005A-0071-0036-FFFD-004C-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-0039-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-003A-FFFD-001D-FFFD-FFFD-0017-0078-FFFD-FFFD-005E-FFFD-0025-0007-0055-FFFD-0021-FFFD-FFFD-012D-FFFD-0076-0038-005E-006F-FFFD-FFFD-000F-0004-FFFD-FFFD-0020-FFFD-FFFD-
0085-FFFD-000E-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-005F-FFFD-FFFD-0016-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-0048-0077-000E-001D-FFFD-0005-0002-000A-FFFD-004F-FFFD-0027-000A-FFFD-003C-0020-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-0021-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-0051-FFFD-0014-FFFD-FFFD-0061-FFFD-0036-001B-0047-FFFD-0057-0017-FFFD-0061-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-002F-002E-002E-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-003C-0006-0392-007E-0049-FFFD-FFFD-004D-0038-FFFD-FFFD-0061-004D-0033-002E-0051-0053-FFFD-0033-FFFD-0033-0031-0057-FFFD-FFFD-1A78-0013-FFFD-FFFD-005A-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-000E-0061-0026-FFFD-004C-FFFD-0048-0046-FFFD-0005-FFFD-0079-0047-FFFD-004B-FFFD-FFFD-0021-0031-0056-0034-FFFD-FFFD-0052-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-0071-FFFD-003D-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-0023-FFFD-006E-0023-FFFD-0078-FFFD-0004-FFFD-001B-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-0055-0075-FFFD-0008-0001-006D-FFFD-0000-0049-001D-0044-010E-FFFD-0021-FFFD-005B-004F-0059-0041-0000-0043-004F-0173-FFFD-0053-FFFD-002F-FFFD-0006-0024-0030-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-000F-FFFD-0031-012E-05CC-FFFD-067D-021F-FFFD-0004-FFFD-005F-FFFD-05DB-003B-0021-0051-FFFD-FFFD-0044-0023-FFFD-0075-0034-003B-001F-FFFD-FFFD-006C-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-0065-FFFD-FFFD-0016-002D-0030-004E-FFFD-FFFD-FFFD-0031-FFFD-0053-000E

Hash string length = 480

I run both console programs on the same computer.

Comment: Fundamentally: a) hashes aren't encoded text, and shouldn't be treated as such; b) `Encoding.Default` is almost *always* the wrong encoding to use in my experience. Convert the hash to text or base64, and you should be fine. You'll need to throw away all the hashes in your database, of course - which will no doubt be inconvenient, but I'm afraid that's the price you pay for handling binary data inappropriately to start with :(

Comment: Now would be a good time to stop using MD5, too... I suspect you could rip out most of your home-rolled authentication and use something off-the-shelf that has been designed by someone with more security experience. This area is one where you really want to lean on the expertise of others.

Comment: Can you write the byte array with spaces, `string.Join(" ", md5.Hash)`, or in a way such that each byte has the same number of chars? Can you tell what `Encoding.Default.WebName` is in both cases? Not all byte arrays are valid for decoding of all `Encoding` instances.

Comment: MD5 just using for showing, that byte arrays are equal. Encoding.Default on my computer  is UTF8. I just don't understand why from equals byte arrays I get different strings.

Comment: Can you write out `string.Join(" ", bytesOfHash)` also, since it is different from `md5.Hash`, presumably?

Comment: Do you believe that MD5 hashes are UTF-8 encoded text? I don't. While it's unfortunate that the handling of invalid data has apparently changed between .NET Core 2.1 and .NET 5, that doesn't mean you're doing the right thing at the moment. And if you're storing the MD5 hash, then it's *not* "just using for showing that byte arrays are equal" - it's presumably designed to avoid storing the plaintext data in your database... MD5 is  not a good choice for that.

Comment: In fact, since we have not seen what `bytesOfHash` is (it must be a lot longer given that UTF-8 produces strings of length 478 or 480), we cannot tell if the difference is really in the UTF-8 decoding. But surely, a "random" sequence of byte is not valid UTF-8! What is `Encoding.Default.DecoderFallback.ToString()` in each case?

Comment: I am guessing that this is caused by .NET 5 using ICU (International Components for Unicode) instead of Natural Language Support for its unicode handling libraries. Since you are interpreting random bytes as text, it's plausible that some byte combinations is translated differently. Note that since you *are* translating random bytes into strings, the exact behavior *is* undocumented and unsupported. Try converting the bytes into strings with `BitConverter.ToString(md5.Hash)` instead of `Encoding.Default.GetString`.

Comment: For completess, so that we can reproduce your results, can you post `GetBytesOfHash`?

Comment: I can't paste all bytesOfHash in comment (it's too large). But I see, that this arrays are equals. Encoding.Default.DecoderFallback.ToString() = System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback (in both cases)

Comment: You can edit the question above, and in the last part add what `BitConverter.ToString(bytesOfHash)` and `string.Join("-", hashString.Select(ch => $"{(ushort)ch:X4}"))` return.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen , thank u. I added BitConverter.ToString(bytesOfHash) and string.Join("-", hashString.Select(ch => $"{(ushort)ch:X4}"))

Comment: Looking at the first diff, can you check if `Encoding.Default.GetString(new byte[] { 0xF4, 0x9D, 0x40, })` gives different strings (with different lengths) on the two .NET versions?

Comment: Yes, strings are different. **Core2.1**: ?@     **.net5**: ??@

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of `Encoding.GetString` on an array of bytes which in no way represents a text string, is meaningless and wrong. So never do that! The rest of this answer is about the way in which the same (illegal!) byte sequence gives different strings in the two versions of .NET.

---

After comments, and addition of actual data to the question, it looks like the reason is indeed differences in the UTF-8 decoders when they encounter illegal sequences of bytes. In particular, when they first see a correct byte starting with bits `11110` meaning the start of a 4-byte encoding, then see a correct byte starting with `10` meaning the first pure "payload" byte (two more of that type expected), but then see a wrong byte in the context, one not starting with `10`, then the decoders disagree on how many U+FFFD 'REPLACEMENT CHARACTER' `�` to emit.

In particular, the asker has confirmed in comments that `Encoding.Default.GetString(new byte[] { 0xF4, 0x9D, 0x40, })` gives `"�@"` in .NET Core 2.1, but `"��@"` in .NET 5. The byte `F4` promises the start of a 4-byte sequence, the byte `9D` looks correct enough as byte 2, but then the plain ASCII byte `40` (meaning `@`) breaks the sequence. So the disagreement is about whether that is shown as `"�@"` or `"��@"`.

The other case where the strings differ is similar, except here the 4-byte sequence is interrupted by a byte starting with `1110` instead of a byte starting with `0`.

I guess more universally you can use `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(new byte[] { 0xF4, 0x9D, 0x40, })` (because `Encoding.Default` may be something else if your OS is set to a language/locale that can be represented with a legacy 1-byte encoding, such as [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page#Windows-125x_series)). *Addition:* I see in the [documentation of `Default`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.default) that it will give UTF-8 on all .NET Core variants (including .NET Core 2.1 and .NET 5). It is only on the old .NET Framework (like .NET Framework 4.8) that `Default` may yield an ANSI code page, like Windows-1252.

Comment: The main problem here is relying on undocumented/unsupported behavior, as translating a random bulk of bytes into a string isn't supposed to work anyway. The correct approach is to use base64 or something similar.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Agreed! Decoding a "random" sequence of bytes as if it were UTF-8 is absolutely meaningless and should not be done. Jon Skeet already explained that in comments to the question. I just wanted to get into the technical details of how the same input array could lead to different resulting string values. Will add a warning in top of my answer.